# Deployment error on Google App engine launcher for python application

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to deploy a python application on google app engine using google app engine launcher.

The Project ID is same as my application name is app.yaml file
But still I am getting the following error in log.

```
appcfg.py:2450 An error occurred processing file '': EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:581). Aborting. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 133, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 129, in run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5509, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5500, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3019, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5156, in __call__
    return method()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3878, in Update
    self._UpdateWithParsedAppYaml(appyaml, self.basepath)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3931, in _UpdateWithParsedAppYaml
    self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, basepath, appyaml, APP_YAML_FILENAME)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3816, in UpdateVersion
    return appversion.DoUpload(paths, openfunc)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2440, in DoUpload
    self.error_fh)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 494, in GetResourceLimits
    resource_limits.update(_GetRemoteResourceLimits(logging_context))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 464, in _GetRemoteResourceLimits
    yaml_data = logging_context.Send('/api/appversion/getresourcelimits')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1750, in Send
    result = self.rpcserver.Send(url, payload=payload, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc_httplib2.py", line 236, in Send
    url, method=method, body=payload, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\httplib2\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1584, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\httplib2\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1332, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\httplib2\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1268, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\httplib2\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1014, in connect
    self.disable_ssl_certificate_validation, self.ca_certs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\httplib2\httplib2\__init__.py", line 80, in _ssl_wrap_socket
    cert_reqs=cert_reqs, ca_certs=ca_certs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 891, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 566, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 788, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:581)
2015-07-13 14:35:47 (Process exited with code 1)
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the source of the error, but "appcfg.py" is deprecated... can you install the Google Cloud SDK and use the "gcloud" command to deploy rather than invoking the old appcfg.py script? https://cloud.google.com/sdk/

Comment: Thank you for suggestion Michael. I am trying it.

Comment: I've been getting the `ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:581)` error quite a lot last week. Not sure why, but after 1-3 attemptes it usually goes away and the app gets finally deployed.

Comment: Still Not able to get the solution to this problem.